# How do I download a TXT and then read it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Okay so I have a program that is supposed to download a TXT file which ONLY contains a URL from my Dropbox, save it on my desktop, and then open the webbrowser like `Process.Start(DownloadedFile)`.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\Desktop"
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy9jpt1em3o6khp/download_location.txt?dl=1", path + "\" + "Download_Location" + ".txt")

Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path + "\Download_Location.txt")
Process.Start(fileReader)
```

Now my problem is that, the program DOES download my txt file and name it correctly. But even if I know that there is text in the text file, when the program downloads it and saves it on my Desktop named "Download_Location.txt", it is empty. The downloaded file doesn't conatin any text even if Im 100% sure that there should be a URL text.

And when my program reached the code where `Process.Start(fileReader)` it gives me an error:

> You can not start the process because no file name is specified.

Thanks a lot! And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: May I ask how it comes that when you construct your `path` variable you concatenate strings with the `&`, but in every place after that you use `+`? You should always use the ampersand (`&`) when concatenating strings as you'll avoid problems related to using the `+` operator.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still the same error. If you try to visit (https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy9jpt1em3o6khp/download_location.txt?dl=1 ) you will see a TXT file downloading and it will contain a URL, but when the program downloads the file, it is empty. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: I never said it'd solve your problem, I just said it's better practice to use the ampersand when concatenating strings becase the plus may cause problems.

Comment: The link you provided does not seem to be a direct link. You can only download the file if you have a direct link to it (which is a link that leads directly to the file, without any redirections). Try using this link instead: `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/Uxdm1CQxQ50LBm5QejnkGLOIXJf8QL2Iui95XjhMUL2Wz4gjzBwiHttuA07RkbOl/file?dl=1`

Comment: You are the best, put your suggestion as the answer of this topic. Thankyou alot!

Comment: No problem. Have been dealing with this sorts of stuff for a long time. :)

Comment: Also just noticed: we're both from Sweden! Good luck in the future!

Comment: Hahaha tack så mycket ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downloading files via a URL you are required to use a direct URL, due to that you download exactly the URL you specify. The reason you can download it from your web browser is because it first loads the page from the first link, then the page tells the browser to redirect to the actual file.

Direct links through DropBox are accessed via the `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` website, which is what you'll need to get the direct link to your file. The reason DropBox uses this system is probably because `dropbox.com/s/...` is yet a bit shorter than `dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/...`

Having this said, switching your download URL from what you have now to: `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/Uxdm1CQxQ50LBm5QejnkGLOIXJf8QL2I‌​ui95XjhMUL2Wz4gjzBwiHttuA07RkbOl/file?dl=1` should work.