# Download public TXT file from Dropbox with VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to download txt file from dropbox and read the content
I have this code but i have an error :(
the code work perfect with pastebin but not working with dropbox

```
Dim w As New WebClient    
    Dim cpuids As String() = Split(w.DownloadString("link here !"), "|")
    Dim cur As String = HWID
    For Each c As String In cpuids
        If cur = c Then
            GoTo authed
        End If
        Next
```

help !

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: Can we get an example of a link you're trying to download? There's a chance you need to add `?raw=1` to your link.

Comment: cant read string correctly ... look im using regex to find string but with dropbox dos'nt find the string as pastebin

Comment: Im added `?raw=1` and its work perfect thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a TXT and then read it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072098/how-do-i-download-a-txt-and-then-read-it)

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working fine with `Pastebin` however with `Dropbox` its just downloading a whole lot of text that isn't making much sense, try this

Go to this link http://www.technorange.com/cloudlinker-direct-link-generator-for-dropboxgoogle-driveone-drive-copy-com/
 copy your download link from dropbox and paste it into the generate a new download link, this will enable you to download files directly from dropbox that will contain the right details.
 I had the same problem once before and managed to fix it by changing my downloads URL name from that website stated above.